# Distribution of urns for non-uniform distribution

Tags: distributions, sample, histogram

Let $X_1,\dots, X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables on a set $X$. Let $j$ be a uniformly random number from $1$ to $n$; define a new random variable

$$ Y(j) = \frac{\left\vert \{i: X_i=X_j\}\right\vert}{n}.$$

That is, $Y(j)$ should follow a distribution of how many samples have the same value.

If the $X_i$ are uniformly random on some finite set, then this is the classic problem of a monkey throwing balls into urns. I'm curious about the case where $X_i$ have other distributions. My specific application is a discretized normal distribution (i.e., divide the real numbers into regular bins, sample a normal distribution, and output which bin it fell into), but I'm curious about this in general.

I think what I am asking could equivalently be phrased as: what is the distribution of the sizes of the bars in a histogram?

Do these distributions have a name/known properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the problem easier to read, I am going to use slightly different notation to you.  I will confine attention to the case where the set of interest $\mathscr{X}$ is a finite set.  Without loss of generality, take $\mathscr{X} \equiv \{ 1,...,m \}$ and let the values of interest have a [categorical distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution):

$$X_1,...,X_n \sim \text{IID Cat}(\mathbf{p})
\quad \quad \quad \mathbf{p} \equiv (p_1,...,p_m).$$

To facilitate the analysis, let $W_J \equiv | \{ i=1,...,n| X_i=X_J \} |$ denote the number of sample values that are equal to the $J$th sample value.  This can be written in alternative form as:

$$W_J = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{I}(X_i = X_J) = 1 + \sum_{i \neq J} \mathbb{I}(X_i = X_J).$$

If we condition on $X_J=x$ then we have:

$$\begin{aligned}
W_J 
= 1 + \sum_{i \neq J} \mathbb{I}(X_i = x)
\sim 1 + \text{Bin}(n-1, p_x). \\[6pt]
\end{aligned}$$

Since $J \sim \text{U}(1,...,n)$ you have $\mathbb{P}(X_J = x) = p_x$, and so application of the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) gives:

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(W_J = w) 
&= \sum_{x=1}^m \mathbb{P}(W_J = w | X_J=x) \cdot \mathbb{P}(X_J=x) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{x=1}^m \text{Bin}( w-1 | n-1, p_x ) \cdot \ p_x \\[6pt]
&= {n-1 \choose w-1} \sum_{x=1}^m p_x^{w} (1-p_x)^{n-w}. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned}$$

As you can see, the random variable $W_J-1$ has a binomial-mixture distribution, and so $W_J$ has a closely related distribution.  We can confirm that the mass function we have derived is valid by checking that it sums to one.  Using the binomial theorem we have:

$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{w=1}^n \mathbb{P}(W_J = w) 
&= \sum_{w=1}^n {n-1 \choose w-1} \sum_{x=1}^m p_x^{w} (1-p_x)^{n-w} \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{x=1}^m p_x (1-p_x)^{n-1} \sum_{w=1}^n {n-1 \choose w-1} \Big( \frac{p_x}{1-p_x} \Big)^{w-1} \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{x=1}^m p_x (1-p_x)^{n-1} \Big( 1 + \frac{p_x}{1-p_x} \Big)^{n-1} \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{x=1}^m p_x (1-p_x)^{n-1} \Big( \frac{1}{1-p_x} \Big)^{n-1} \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{x=1}^m p_x =1. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned}$$

This confirms the validity of the density.  In the uniform case where $\mathbf{p} = (\tfrac{1}{m},...,\tfrac{1}{m})$ you have:

$$\mathbb{P}(W_J = w) = {n-1 \choose w-1} \frac{(m-1)^{n-w}}{m^{n-1}}.$$

This gives you the distribution for $W_J$ and so the corresponding distribution for $Y_J = W_J/n$ is a simple scaled variation of this.  I do not recognise this distribution by name, but it should not be too difficult to derive its properties.  As stated, $W_J-1$ has a binomial-mixture distribution; mixtures of binomial distributions are examined in [Blischke (1964)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2283005) and various other papers.

Comment: Thanks, that's a surprisingly pleasant equation. Should the last line be $\binom{n-1}{w-1}\frac{(m-1)^{n-w}}{m^{n-1}}$? It looks like you substituted $p_x=1/n$ in the second term, rather than $p_x=1/m$.

Comment: Well spotted --- corrected.

Comment: I think I will end up using this in a paper. Do you want me to cite this question (following the stack exchange citation guidelines), cite Blischke directly, or something else?

Comment: If you use this derivation in your paper then it would be a good idea to cite this answer (thanks) and it might also be worth citing Blischke to note broader information about binomial mixtures.  (If you need any help with your paper, shoot me an email.)